# Radio Button not working. Will select but not background color

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, radio-button

I'm using bootstrap to create inline radio buttons. But neither are being selected.

I've tried several things like changing the for attributes, name. Calling the bootstrap function differently. Also tried actually changing the ::before color from the bootstrap function.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-inline">
    <label for="rd_Gender" class="col-md-6 col-form-label text-left">
        Gender:<span id="spnGender" style="color:red; display:none;"> *</span>
    </label>
    <div id="rd_Gender" onclick="clearRatings()" class="form-inline d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <label class="custom-control-label female" for="rd_Gender_0">
                <input id="rd_Gender_0" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="Gender" value="50" checked="checked" />
                {{calcData.prCalcLabels.lblFemale}}
             </label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio ml-5 custom-control-inline">
            <label class="custom-control-label male" for="rd_Gender_1">
                <input id="rd_Gender_1" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="Gender" value="51" />
               {{calcData.prCalcLabels.lblMale}}
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm expecting one or the other radio button to be selected. It selects but background doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-inline">
    <label for="rd_Gender" class="col-md-6 col-form-label text-left">
        Gender:<span id="spnGender" style="color:red; display:none;"> *</span>
    </label>
    <div id="rd_Gender" onclick="clearRatings()" class="form-inline d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input id="rd_Gender_0" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="Gender" value="50" checked="checked" />
            <label class="custom-control-label female" for="rd_Gender_0">                    
                {{calcData.prCalcLabels.lblFemale}}
             </label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio ml-5">
            <input id="rd_Gender_1" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="Gender" value="51" />
            <label class="custom-control-label male" for="rd_Gender_1">
               {{calcData.prCalcLabels.lblMale}}
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```